# Question about reg exps in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write regular expression that will parse strings like this:

```
Build-Depends: cdbs, debhelper (>=5), smthelse
```

I want to extract package names (without version numbers and brackets).

I wrote something like this:

```
$line =~ /^Build-Depends:\s*(\S+)\s$/
```

But it's not exactly what I want.

Does someone know how to manage it?

P.S. I just want to get the list: "cdbs debhelper smthelse" as a result

Comment: what does it capture ? How is it different from what you want ? Does your string always have a white space at the end of input string ?

Comment: I just want to get the list:  "cdbs debhelper smthelse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do what you want: `/\s(\S*)(?:\s\(.*?\))?(?:,|$)/g`

**Edit**: You'd call it like this to loop through all the results:

```
while ($str =~ /\s(\S*)(?:\s\(.*?\))?(?:,|$)/g) {
    print "$1 is one of the packages.\n";
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly not( It's just extract the first one while I need all names. By the way how can I get the number of extracted packages?

Comment: I've added `g` at the end of the regex, which should make it 'global' and make it find all the matches (depending on how you're calling this regex, it might not be needed, so I didn't put it in at first).

Comment: Npw it's also doesn't work. 
if ($line =~ /\s(\S*)(?:\s\(.*?\))?(?:,|$)/g) {
    print "$2\n";
} Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 8.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do. You wanted a regex that would match all of them in one go. I don't think that's possible with a simple regex. You're best off using one regex and matching it several times, then looping through the matches. I've edited my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's what I really need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With your regex `/^Build-Depends:\s*(\S+)\s$/` you are matching until the end of string.
Try `/^Build-Depends:\s*(\S+)\s/` instead.

Comment: Then I just extract the first name with ',' symbol at the end.

Comment: For example I cannot use $2 variable since it's uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the types of package names listed here.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @packs;
my $line = "Build-Depends: cdbs, debhelper (>=5), smthelse";

if ( $line =~ /^Build-Depends: (.+)$/ ) { # get everything
    @packs = split /,+\s*/, $1;
    s/\([^)]+\)//g for @packs; # remove version stuff
}

print "$_\n" for @packs;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the input on whitespace and print each element if a `(` is not present?
Something like this perhaps

```
perl -lane 'foreach $_ (@F[1..scalar(@F)]) {print if not m/\(/}'
cdbs,
debhelper
smthelse
```